# vpython view from position and rotation

Tags: python, perspectivecamera, vpython

I am sorry if this question seems somewhat vague.I am interested in if it is possible to obtain the "view" from a given position (and rotation, obviously) and translating such a view into an image one could manipulate.

So essentially, given a position and rotation, using vpython, one could save or manipulate the image of such a view while still retaining a standard view on vpython's display.For example, say I might want to look around a cube and, at whim, press space to save an image of the perspective of such a cube via a separate camera located at the cube.

Is this in any way possible in vpython? I fear that it does not support multiple cameras, let alone the manipulation of their perspective?

Comment: Sorry if this makes no sense.

Comment: Some context may help- I am attempting to create a view of vaguely humanoid looking blocks- at the same time I want to manipulate the view from their perspectives so as to allow them to coordinate their environment.